# Random reboots win 10

Tags: hardware-failure, crash, reboot

Recently my custom build PC started to crash and reboot at random times. When ever the reboot loop starts it seems to only get worse. To the point where all I hear is boot-up beeps. 
The pc is about 3 years old, I have not had any problems with in until now. 
I have searched the web for any and all possible fixes, I have replaced the motherboard, hard drive, psu and even tried pulling ram cards out to see if one of them could be bad and still the issue persists.
I have tried to fix it 3 times so far replacing a different part each time, the weird thing is that the pc will work flawlessly for 2 days then the reboot issue comes back.

1. First fix 
   Replaced old cpu hydro cooled heatsink without any change.
2. Replaced the psu 
   Worked fine for 2 days then rebooted couple of times and stopped booting up completely
3. Figures it was the mother board swapped out my old Asus sabertooth z87 for a z97 model, worked fine for 2 days then the restarts came back
4. I noticed the pc was running slow and glitching so thought it could be the ssd, that same day the pc crashed and the ssd could not be detected in the bios
5. Replaced the SSD with HDD and it worked fine for 3 days, now the restarts are back again.
6. Just now i tried alternating the ram cards, as in tried to boot with one or the other to see if that makes a difference, the pc continues to crash to the point where it will even crash in BIOS.

Current system

- Asus sabertooth z97 motherboard
- [Intel i7 4790K](https://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz)
- G-Skill 2x8GB RAM
- [Sapphire Radeon R9 280 3GB](http://www.sapphiretech.com/catapage_pd.asp?cataid=73&lang=eng)
- Roswel capstone 80plus 750W PSU
- Corsair H60 hydro series cpu cooler
- Seagate 500GB HDD

Comment: While it's likely that you're looking for a fix you don't mention it at all. Is there any pattern to the programs you're running? Is your PC getting unusually hot? Did you try to reinstall your operating system? Which one are you using?

Comment: The system is running cool, that was the first thing I mentioned and I have tried swapping heat sinks to see if that made a difference but with no luck. And yes the I did reinstall the OS on a new drive that Is currently in it

Comment: There isn't a single mention of temperature in your question. You do mention that you changed the cooler but there is no mention of whenever that had any impact on the temperature. Go and actually check them. With the number of components you have replaced there isn't much left you could replace. Do you get any kind of stop code or similar? Disable the automatic reboot on bluescreen if it immediately reboots. Do you have any overclocking place (CPU or maybe XMP for RAM)?

Comment: The temperature stayed at a constant 36C for cpu and 26 for the board. No overclocking for either cpu or ram.

Comment: Is there any high power equipment connected to the same electrical circuit? Do you have other devices on it that are acting strange? Did check your motherboard manual on what the beeps should be indicating? What do you mean it was running slow and glitching? Did you consider running something like memtest to check your ram modules?

Answer (score 0):

If you're crashing in BIOS you have one of these problems:

- Flaky Power supply/power
- RAM problems
- Thermal Problems (too hot)
- Motherboard Chip problem (look for blown capacitors)
- CPU Hardware problem

Unplug everything but the minimal amount of hardware necessary to boot.

Use software to run RAM test: memtest86+

Feel CPU cooler when crash occurs to determine if CPU is overheating.

Start swapping parts till the crash goes away.

Comment: I have motinitored the cpu temp when I could boot to bios and it stayed around 36C, the board has been replaced and so has the ram. How can I check if the cpu failed?

Comment: Swap it with different CPU

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the original post I have tried to replace several components and the pc seemed to work but the issue came back still. 
I currently have a new mother board in, and I replaced the hard drive and installed a new system, I did have an additional drive hooked up but it is not required for boot. 
I have tried booting with one ram card and that didn’t work either. 
I tried replacing the psu but the same problem came back still so I put the old one back in
Right now if I turn on the pc all I get is the system posting short beep and then it crashes

Comment: I don't get why you would post this as an answer? Shouldn't this rather be an edit to your question?

Comment: I am new to this site and now quite sure how things work here, sorry bout that

Comment: No problem, maybe check out the [help center](https://superuser.com/help). It does have various topics that explain a bit how the site works.